# Weird graphics/motherboard boot issue

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card

On an old PC I have there is an issue with the graphics card.

Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460
Motherboard: eMachines EMCP73VT-PM
Power supply: Thermalake TR2-430

When I do a cold boot there is a % chance that the card will not be detected, and the onboard graphics will be used instead. This does not happen when coming out of sleep/hibernation or when restarting.

Is this likely to be a graphics card, motherboard or PSU issue? I have another (weaker) graphics card that does not suffer from these problems in the same configuration. Thanks.

Comment: How are you determining the card isn't being detected?

Comment: It may be detected, but often the video goes to the onboard graphics instead of the external card. It seems random. If I cycle power repeatedly when the PC is shut down, then eventually it will switch over to the correct card.

Comment: This ^^^ comment does NOT answer the question in my first comment. So far it's only your assertion that it isn't being detected. How do you **know** the *video goes to the onboard graphics*, do you have two monitors independently connected or what?

Comment: I physically switch the monitor video cable back and forth between the two cards until I see an image.

Comment: Keep doing that and you'll end up with no board at all. VGA connections are not designed for "hot-plugging" unlike the digital ones (HDMI, etc.). And if the BIOS is set to to "auto", I'm afraid that doing that may well be the cause of the behavior. First of all make sure the discrete card is explicitly selected in BIOS. MBs of that vintage, if set to auto, must rely on correct cable detection.